# The mixed-mode assembly is created with runtime version'v1.1.4322' and cannot be loaded into runtime 4.0 without further configuration information

Tags: c#, .net, directx

## C# ERROR WITH DIRECTX3D Library

I have an error when I try to run my application in C# with the DirectX library.

This is not the code but the App.config configuration file.

It shows me this error when I launch the application:

> "The mixed-mode assembly is created with runtime version'v1.1.4322 'and can not be loaded into runtime 4.0 without further configuration information."

I looked on the internet and was told to write this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy ="false">
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku =".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
   </Startup>
</Configuration>
```

In the App.config file but it does not work anymore.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I would recommend using [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) if you really want to mess around with low-level DirectX.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, what happened?

Answer (score 2):

Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies have been deprecated a long, long time. They were written for .NET 1.1 and worked with .NET 2.0 - 3.5. They don't work with .NET 4.0 or later nor do they work with `/platform:anycpu` or `/platform:x64`. They are only deployed by the [legacy DirectSetup package](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup/).

Use [SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/) if you want a drop-in replacement for the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies, or use [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) if you want something more modern.

See [DirectX and .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/12/09/directx-and-net/)